# Will DB connection leakage cause too many inactive session in Oracle?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I was assigned a task about fixing too many inactive session  in Oracle database which used in our Java application. We found there was java method which didn't close the JDBC connetion. I know this is a DB connection leakage, but I am not sure if it is the cause of the too many inactive session. I don't know if O can get to know which Java process cause this issue. Can someone help me?

Comment: If your Java application uses a connection pool, (some of) those inactive session might not be leaked connections, but simply connections in the pool that are currently not in use. However, unclosed connections cause a leak (whether you use a connection pool or not), so the obvious way to answer your question is to fix that leak you identified and then check if the number of inactive sessions goes down after deploying the fixed version.

Answer (score 2):

> I know this is a DB Connection leakage but I am not sure if it is the reason cause the too many too many inactive session.

Probably.

If each time you get a JDBC Connection you do actually create a new connection then you will also start a new session and when you do not close the connection then you will have an inactive session and the number of sessions will grow.

If you are using connection pooling then, when you close the connection, the connection is not actually closed but is returned to the pool. When the next connection is required it will request a connection from the pool and you will reuse the previous connection and the previous connection's session. In this case you should not see an increase in the total number of sessions while the connections are reused from the connection pool but you might see inactive sessions that are the pooled connections which are not currently in use.

It sounds like you are not using connection pooling and then the number of sessions will directly correlate to the number of connections.